# LibGDX cannot save to internal file

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to save the state of the game in a file, so I can read it at the next start.
The Problem is, that I get a exception, if I try to save something internal.
If I try to save it local all work fine.
I save the file as a Json.

```
Bird bird = new Bird();
bird.setName("Foo");
bird.setSkin(new Texture("data/foo.png"));
bird.save(Gdx.files.internal("bird.json"));
```

The save mthod:

```
Json json = new Json();
file.writeString(json.prettyPrint(this), false);
```

> Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Error writing file: bird.json (Internal)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:349)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:335)
>       at com.buschmannmichael.fattybird.core.Bird.save(Bird.java:31)
>       at com.buschmannmichael.fattybird.game.FattyBirdGame.create(FattyBirdGame.java:16)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:137)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:115)
>   Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cannot write to an internal file: bird.json
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writer(FileHandle.java:315)
>       at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.writeString(FileHandle.java:346)
>       ... 5 more

Whats the problem of LibGDX, where I should save the files, so I can run the game on android, desktop and html ?
(I tested this method I showed above only on desktop, maybe it works on android but I want a solution for all platforms)

Maybe someone can help me :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Gdx.file.internal is **read-only**. You can use ***local*** file or ***preferences*** (creates an internal .xml file where you can store small amount of data). It is perfect for game saving.

Take a look at : https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

You can also use an external file (stored on sdcard), but you can optionally encrypt it, as it can be edited by the user.

Comment: Sometimes allowing something to be edited by the user isn't such a bad thing.

Comment: Yes, but I think you should create  in-game features for the editable parts, because if you give him full privileges, he could completely manipulate the game process :)

Comment: If this is a single player game, that's not an issue. They are only cheating themselves. If this is a multiplayer game and a local file can affect the state of the game for all other player, you have failed to design a secure game.

Comment: It's true ! In online multiplayer games I think you should store important files on a server, if the framework has this feature. Is it a good idea ?

Comment: Yes is it, the local way is to unsafe. :D